# Host Multiple websites on azure virtual machine

Tags: azure, iis-7, virtual-machine

I Have created a virtual machine on azure and hosted one web applications(react and nodejs web app) with iis web server.

Now I want to create a one more (Wordpress) web applications with same Virtual machine on iis web server.

Is it possible in azure to host multiple websites with same ip address of virtual machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, IS can manage different sites with host headers functionality

[**Host multiple Web sites on one server.**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc753729(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Answer (score 0):

Hosting multiple websites is supported by IIS.

If you want to share same port number for multiple websites, then please remember to specify public domain name for each site.

If you don't have so much public domain and you just want to access your website via External Firewall IP address, then please set different Port number for them.